# How to determine Big O comparing two arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, big-o

My algorithm skills are lackluster. I created a method to see if two arrays contain the same elements (duplicates don't matter):

```
one = [1, "taco", 3, 2, :piece, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
two = [:piece, 2, 5, 4, 1, "taco", 3]

def same_elements?(array_one, array_two)
  return true if ( (array_one - array_two).empty? && (array_two - array_one).empty? )
  return false
end

same_elements?(one, two)
```

This returns true (which is correct). The problem is, I am not sure what the efficiency of this algorithm is. My first guess is O(n^2) since we have to check both a-b and b-a. I know that O(n^2) is pretty terrible. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: That wouldn't be O(n^2) it would be O(4n) but as coefficients are ignored this is O(n). This isn't a particularly bad algorithm. Array subtraction in ruby is O(2n) to the best of my belief.

Comment: Thanks Eli! I believe O(1) and O(log n) are would be better than this? I don't think there's a way to incorporate that into this though?

Comment: It is more accurate to describe the complexity in terms of two variables, since the complexity is dependent on the length of two independent arrays. The source code for set difference (from the [Ruby 2.3 docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html)) appears to show that the difference operation is O(mn).

Comment: Your method is fine provided you consider `[1,1,2]` and `[1,2]` to contain the same elements. If so, just make the body of the method `array_one - array_two).empty? && (array_two - array_one).empty?`, which, being the last statement executed, will return `true` or `false`. btw, "lackluster" (or "lacklustre") is one word.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the info!

Comment: Also, thanks @JoelCornett for the O(mn) reference!

Comment: You could solve this other ways such as `[one,two].map(&:uniq).sort_by(&:size).reverse.reduce(:-).empty?` or `((one & two).uniq - one).empty?` but your solution is definitely sufficient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short answer

**O(n+m)** on average

The worst case is O(nm), but it only happens if you really want to make it happen (see last paragraph).

If `array_one` is chosen to be bigger than `array_two`, O(m+n) is just O(n), so this algorithm runs in linear time on average.

## Alternative

Another shorter way to check would be :

```
one = [1, "taco", 3, 2, :piece, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
two = [:piece, 2, 5, 4, 1, "taco", 3]

puts Set[*one] == Set[*two] #=> true
# or
puts one.to_set == two.to_set #=> true
```

## Small refactoring

```
return true if x
return false
```

is equivalent to just

```
x
```

So your code can be written :

```
def same_elements?(array_one, array_two)
  (array_one - array_two).empty? && (array_two - array_one).empty?
end
```

## Benchmark

I created one array with 1E6 elements, half of which are random numbers between 0 and 199999 (for collisions), the other half being plain Ruby objects.

The other array is just the first one, shuffled randomly.

```
N = 1_000_000

one = (1..N).map{rand < 0.5 ? rand(N/5) : Object.new}
two = one.sort_by{rand}
```

It takes 1 min to compare the sets, and [fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) reports that set comparison is about 20% faster than the OP's method.

For smaller arrays of integers, the OP's method was a bit faster.

Note: code proposed by @engineersmnky in comments was reported to have similar speed than the other methods.

## Time complexity

Your code is surely *not* `O(nm)` when used with usual Arrays.

Approximate times are :

- 1s for 1E4
- 8s for 1E5
- 160s for 1E6

Looking at [`rb_ary_diff`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) in `array.c`, it's no wonder all the methods described above run in the same time : they basically work the same.

`rb_ary_diff` creates a hash table for `array_two` ( in O(m)), and iterates over each element of `array_one` (in O(n)), looking for the value in the hash table (O(1) on average). The whole operation would be O(n+m) on average.

This [blog post](http://blog.flatironlabs.com/post/83827497166/ruby-array-set-intersection-a-rails-use-case-and) analyses [set intersection](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-26), which is implemented in a very similar way.

Doing it twice doesn't change anything, so the overall time complexity stays O(n+m).

## Looking for O(mn)

One way to make this algorithm O(mn) is to completely disable the hash method. There's no reason to do so, except to prove that it's a very bad idea.

With 10_000 KeyObjects :

```
class KeyObject < Object
end
```

the set comparison takes less than 1 s.

With 10_000 KeyObjects :

```
class KeyObject < Object
  def hash
    1
  end
end
```

the set comparison takes more than 14 mins!

The probability that 2 distinct, random Ruby objects have the same hash is about 1E-20. Strictly speaking, the worst case for this algorithm is O(mn), but it will **never** happen if you don't go looking for it. Finding a collision with 2 elements isn't trivial, finding a collision with 1E6 elements is not going to happen by chance.

Comment: Thanks so much for the in-depth response Eric! Good call on the refactoring notes as well. This makes a lot more sense now. Appreciate it!

Comment: It's also worthwhile noting, that O(n+m) is linear time. Great explanation on the whole!

Comment: Your benchmark is not complete because it does not include cases where the worst case scenario is exhibited. Can you please built one such case? That would be very interesting and maybe difficult. But this difficulty does not rule out the possibility that it exists. So no, time complexity is O(mn).

Comment: @PetrosB This would be surprising. Do you have any reference for your claim? "Chapter 7" of http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope deals extensively with hash tables. Hashing entries is O(n), with occasional rehashing when bins become too big. Retrieving a value is O(1). The only slow example in the chapter is with custom Object where hash method is defined to be constant.

Comment: Again, retrieving a value in worst case is O(n). You can google it. Also, the book from the link is closed. It'd be good if you could give something that everyones has access to.

Comment: "Ruby under a microscope" is the bible for documentation on Ruby internals. Please don't tell me to use google, and please provide a reference to your claim.

Comment: See my update. If you don't disable the hash method, you'll be fine.

Comment: I think you're confused. An algorithm's time complexity has nothing to do with a language's internals. My reference to you would be one of the numerous undergraduate texts on the subject. And of course, a little bit of willingness.

Comment: No! The question asks for a given algorithm its time complexity and this answer is based on 3 test cases and their actual CPU times as well as on the implementation language's internal details! This is wrong. We're talking about big O, thus, the way the language is implemented is completely irrelevant. In any case, since the OP accepts this answer that's just fine with me.

Answer (score 3):

Let the size of first and second array be m and n respectively. Looking at `rb_ary_diff`'s source code (see Joel Cornett's comment above), there's a `for` loop which runs O(m) times. Inside the loop there's a call that seems to search the hash. This operation in general takes O(n) time. Thus, assuming that all other calls are asymptotically faster than O(mn), then the overall difference function complexity is O(mn). Calling this function twice followed by an emptyness check results in your algorithm being O(mn).

On average hash search is constant, i.e., O(1), which means that in this case your algorithm performs in O(n). Still, hash search worst case complexity is O(n) meaning your algorithm is O(mn). It's a good exercise to find an example which demonstrates this.

Comment: This is wrong, and the algorithm appears to be much faster than O(mn)

Comment: Yes, it appears I was wrong. `O(m+n)` might be a better guess, but @EricDuminil has the right idea by using profiling for verification. I assume that `ary_make_hash(...)` is O(n) and that `st_lookup(...)` and `rb_ary_push(...)` are both O(1).

Comment: @EricDuminil The algorithm appears to be faster because on average hash search is O(1) but its (worst case) complexity is still O(n). As an exercise you can look into the hash function code and try to find an example where the running time will increase polynomially.

Comment: @PetrosB: The burden of proof is on you. Please don't just leave it as an exercise.

Comment: @EricDuminil I don't need to prove anything. I'm just saying that your example is naive enough to be a proof on its own. You reminded me of a teapot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell's_teapot

Comment: You're sitting on the wrong side of this argument ;)

Comment: The confusion comes from "This operation in general takes O(n) time". This sentence is wrong IMHO. Your edit is better, but contradicts the 1st paragraph.

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm sorry but I can't do anything else to convince you if you don't want to.

Comment: Can't we just agree on "hash lookup is O(1) on average with a (very rare) worst case of O(n)"?